# How do I make Selenium RC to not move the browser window?

Tags: python, selenium, window, selenium-rc

Is there a way to specify where Selenium RC spawns the browser window?

When I run my test script, Selenium RC opens 2 windows in the browser, the Selenium RC window and the AUT, and the Selenium RC window takes up most of my screen space. Ideally, I want to control where their location and size separately, but if not, it would be nice to at least make the AUT maximized so that I can eyeball some stuff. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried `window_maximize()`. Although it does make the AUT window bigger, it is located in the bottom of the screen - only the top 1/4 is visible. I am using Selenium RC with Python on a Mac if that matters.

Comment: Sorry, just read the end of it.. Actually yeah i witnessed the problem too. But with Java and MAC. I do think it is a Mac thing because on my windows box it just works fine :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works from java:

```
selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().moveTo((" + h + "),(" + v + "))");
selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().resizeTo(" + w + "," + h + ")");
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found an alternative that works which is just (in Python)

sel.get_eval("window.moveTo(0, 25);")

A small note is that if you moveTo() in a Mac, any v that is less than ~23 would just move your window all the way to the top, because you cannot move any app over the menubar.

Comment: The same ~23 limit occurs on Windows as well. I looked at the selenium source code and saw a comment about that, something they're doing because of some other issue. Frustrating.